# Dojo gridx filter: multiple calls made to server onkeypress while using gridx filter

Tags: dojo, dojo.gridx

A call goes to server every time i type a key in 'Value' field for filtering.
The call should go only when I type on filter button.

*Note: The grid store is a JSON rest store.*

Is there any solution to prevent those api call on every keypress? It should only call the api when i press Filter button

Comment: Because every time you type something, the store is queried to suggest a value.

Comment: Is there any solution to prevent those api call on every keypress? It should only call the api when i press Filter button

Comment: Not using an autocomplete input for the filter value, but AFAIK the input types are based on the data type for the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With latest versions of dojo and gridx: Setting the autoComplete property to false for the columns, stopped this behavior.

Use property: ***autoComplete: false*** for the columns

Answer (score 1):

When you create the grid, try adding the attribute `quickFilterAutoApply: false`, this will forbid the query to the store from auto trigger by key event

Comment: quickFilterAutoApply: false, did not work for me:( Can you tell me for which gridx module this property is applicable?

Comment: gridx/modules/quickFilter

Answer (score 0):

Using ItemFileReadStore instead of JSONRest prevents calls to the server even if autocompleate is on